Trying to figure out how to add mouse control with an embedded dosbox emulator on Google sites
I have been tasked by my History Teacher to try to get a Dosbox emulator up on a google sites so the class can use it to play older MS-Dos games, the one mishap unfortunately is that I can not figure out how to add any form of mouse control after installing a game onto Dosbox, any fix?
I tried fixing the embed and trying to find any research on any way to get a mouse control for it, but to no avail
